# script to backup file deleting file

Tags: 12.04, bash, scripts, backup

Working on a bash script to take backup of a file, but the problem i get is that mv delete the file or rename it and create a file with the backupname.

Script:

```
test="/home/sysadmin/test/hei2.back"

if [ -e "$test" ]
then
  echo "$test exist.\n"
else
  mv  /home/sysadmin/test/hei.txt /home/sysadmin/test/hei2.back

fi
```

Comment: You can use `cp` to copy a file. Is that what you need, if not please clarify your question.

Comment: test="home/sysadmin/test/hei2.back" ???, it should be /home >>  test=``/home/sysadmin/test/hei2.back``

Comment: I want to make a copy of the file, because I am going to make edits in the file and its best to make a backup of that file so I dont lose any important data.

Comment: Qasim bhai, thank you! Is it best to use mv or cp?

Comment: [`cp`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/cp.1.html) means copy, [`mv`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/mv.1.html) means move

Answer (score 0):

As also suggested by others, do `cp` instead of `mv`.

```
cp  /home/sysadmin/test/hei.txt /home/sysadmin/test/hei2.back
```

`cp` : It's used to copy a file/folder.

`mv` : It's used to move/rename a file/folder.

You can learn more on **cp** and **mv**. Go to your terminal and type

1. man cp (Describes various option available in "cp")
2. man mv (Describes various option available in "mv")